# Building LXC, LXD Image

Tags: lxc, ubuntu-core, lxd

Is it possible when using LXC,LXD images and containers that I can build my OWN image for a specific Ubuntu distro? then I use it as a container. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

you can convert a container in a image with this:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:trusty image_container
...
...(you can use lxc launch ubuntu:xenial ... for a different ubuntu release)
...
lxc exec image_container bash
...
...(prepare your container to be setup for be a new image...) 
....
lxc publish image_container --alias local_image
```

after this you can see your local_image in your container like local image server.